# error when running laravel migration declaration of InspectorInterface must be compatible

Tags: laravel, migration

I get this error after trying to migrate my laravel project.
I don't understand what is causing it. Any suggestions?

```
pietrolodirizzini@Pietro-MBP bellamantova % php artisan migrate   
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Whoops\Handler\Handler::setInspector(Whoops\Inspector\InspectorInterface $inspector) must be compatible with Whoops\Handler\HandlerInterface::setInspector(Whoops\Exception\Inspector $inspector) in /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/Handler.php on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Handler' not found in /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Provider.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: NunoMaduro\Collision\Provider->__construct(NULL, NULL)
#1 /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#2 /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('NunoMaduro\\Coll...')
#3 /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('NunoMaduro\\Coll...', Array)
#4 /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~C in /Users/pietrolodirizzini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/laravel/bellamantova/vendor/nunomaduro/collision/src/Provider.php on line 49
```